# How to update LinearLayout when clicking recycler view item in a bottom sheet fragment?

Tags: java, android

I have a Linear Layout view, when you click the view ,it pops up a bottom dialog fragment, the dialog contains a recycler view (with data from a DB), and when you click on any of the recycler view item in the bottom sheet dialog, it should set it as selected and update the Linear Layout to the selected recycler item

This might sound confusing so I have added pictures of what i'm trying to achieve, as well as what I've coded so far

- From the image below the Linear Layout is Labelled (1)
- Clicking the Linear Layout (1) opens a bottom sheet fragment with a recycler view
- Clicking on any recycler view item should update the Linear Layout (1)
  with the selected item

[image]

**AccountPickerDialog.java**

```
public class AccountPickerDialog  extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    private ArrayList<Wallet> userWalletList;

    boolean mIsRequest = false;
    private ShimmerFrameLayout mShimmerViewContainer;

    public AccountPickerDialog() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.account_picker, container, false);

        mShimmerViewContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmer_view_container);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
//        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getContext(),
//                DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        //initializing the walletlist
        userWalletList = new ArrayList<>();
        loadUserWallets();

        return view;
    }

    private void loadUserWallets() {

        if(mIsRequest)
            return;
        mIsRequest= true;
        userWalletList.clear();

        User user = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(getContext()).getUser();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URLs.URL_USER_WALLET_LIST + user.getId(),
                response -> {
                    mIsRequest = false;
                    try {
                        //converting the string to json object
                        JSONObject object=new JSONObject(response);
                        //getting data array from json response object
                        JSONArray array=object.getJSONArray("data");

                        for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++) {

                            //getting wallet object from json array
                            JSONObject userWallets=array.getJSONObject(i);

                            //adding the wallet to wallet list
                            userWalletList.add(new Wallet(
                                    userWallets.getInt("id"),
                                    userWallets.getInt("user_id"),
                                    userWallets.getString("wallet_name"),
                                    userWallets.getInt("wallet_id"),
                                    userWallets.getInt("wallet_type"),
                                    userWallets.getDouble("balance")
                            ));
                        }

                        //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                        if (!isAdded()) return;
                        AccountPickerAdapter adapter = new AccountPickerAdapter(getActivity(),getChildFragmentManager(), userWalletList);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        // stop animating Shimmer and hide the layout
                        mShimmerViewContainer.stopShimmerAnimation();
                        mShimmerViewContainer.setVisibility(GONE);
//                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                },
                error -> {
                    mIsRequest = false;
//                        progressDialog.dismiss();
//                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                });

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext()).add(stringRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mShimmerViewContainer.startShimmerAnimation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        mShimmerViewContainer.stopShimmerAnimation();
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

**AccountPickerAdapter.java**

```
public class AccountPickerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AccountPickerAdapter.DataObjectHolder>  {

    private static String TAG = AccountPickerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mCtx;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    private ArrayList<Wallet> userWalletList;
    private static AccountPickerAdapter.MyClickListener myClickListener;

    public AccountPickerAdapter(Context mCtx, FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<Wallet> userWalletList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        this.userWalletList = userWalletList;
    }

    public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView walletname;
        TextView walletbalance;
        TextView walletid, destinationAccount;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            walletname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.account_picker_name);
            walletbalance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.account_picker_balance);
            walletid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.wallet_id);
            destinationAccount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.destination_account);
//            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
//            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

//        @Override
//        public void onClick(View v) {
//            myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
//        }
    }

//    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
//        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
//    }



    @Override
    public AccountPickerAdapter.DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.account_picker_item, parent, false);
        final AccountPickerAdapter.DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new AccountPickerAdapter.DataObjectHolder(view);

        return dataObjectHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AccountPickerAdapter.DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,###.##");
        formatter.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        Double doubleBalance = userWalletList.get(position).getBalance();
        String numberFormatBalance = formatter.format(doubleBalance);
        holder.walletname.setText(userWalletList.get(position).getWalletName());
        holder.walletbalance.setText(String.valueOf(numberFormatBalance));
        holder.walletid.setText(String.valueOf(userWalletList.get(position).getId()));
        holder.destinationAccount.setText(String.valueOf(userWalletList.get(position).getDestinationAccount()));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userWalletList.size();
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }
}
```

**Fragment Containing the Linear Layout to be updated**

```
public class ReceivePageDialog extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    View selectAccount; //The layout view to be updated

    public ReceivePageDialog() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receive_page, container, false);

        selectAccount = view.findViewById(R.id.source_account_spinner); //Linear Layout view to be updated
        selectAccount.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            AccountPickerDialog accountPickerDialog = new AccountPickerDialog(); //This launches the wallet picker bottom sheet
            accountPickerDialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), accountPickerDialog.getTag());
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog=(BottomSheetDialog)super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        bottomSheetDialog.setOnShowListener(dialog -> {
            BottomSheetDialog dialogc = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;
            FrameLayout bottomSheet =  dialogc.findViewById(R.id.design_bottom_sheet);

            BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels);
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
        });
        return bottomSheetDialog;
    }
}
```

**Question**

Is it possible to update the linear layout by selecting a bottom sheet item? If yes, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Hmm you already done why you need change it to spiner. Bottomsheet is good for material design

Comment: I'm not looking to change to spinner per se, I'm just looking to update the linear layout view when I select a bottom sheet item

Comment: You should change your title to how to update item when clicked in BottomSheetDialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should init `Listener` to `ViewHolder`

```
public class AccountPickerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AccountPickerAdapter.DataObjectHolder>  {

    private static String TAG = AccountPickerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private Context mCtx;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    private ArrayList<Wallet> userWalletList;
    private AccountPickerAdapter.MyClickListener myClickListener;

    public AccountPickerAdapter(Context mCtx, FragmentManager fragmentManager, ArrayList<Wallet> userWalletList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
        this.userWalletList = userWalletList;
    }

    public Wallet getItemByPos(int pos) {
        return userWalletList.get(pos);
    }

    public static class DataObjectHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView walletname;
        TextView walletbalance;
        TextView walletid, destinationAccount;
        private AccountPickerAdapter.MyClickListener myClickListener;

        public DataObjectHolder(View itemView, AccountPickerAdapter.MyClickListener listener;) {
            super(itemView);
            walletname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.account_picker_name);
            walletbalance = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.account_picker_balance);
            walletid = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.wallet_id);
            destinationAccount = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.destination_account);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            myClickListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
        }
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
        this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
    }



    @Override
    public AccountPickerAdapter.DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx).inflate(R.layout.account_picker_item, parent, false);
        final AccountPickerAdapter.DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new AccountPickerAdapter.DataObjectHolder(view);

        return dataObjectHolder;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(AccountPickerAdapter.DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###,###,###,###.##");
        formatter.setDecimalSeparatorAlwaysShown(true);
        formatter.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        Double doubleBalance = userWalletList.get(position).getBalance();
        String numberFormatBalance = formatter.format(doubleBalance);
        holder.walletname.setText(userWalletList.get(position).getWalletName());
        holder.walletbalance.setText(String.valueOf(numberFormatBalance));
        holder.walletid.setText(String.valueOf(userWalletList.get(position).getId()));
        holder.destinationAccount.setText(String.valueOf(userWalletList.get(position).getDestinationAccount()));

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userWalletList.size();
    }

    public interface MyClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
    }
}
```

```
public class AccountPickerDialog  extends BottomSheetDialogFragment implements AccountPickerAdapter.MyClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {
            Wallet wallet = mAdapter.getItemByPos(position)
            View view = ((ReceivePageDialog)getParentFragmen()). selectAccount;
            // find child view and update here
        }
}
```

Init `mAdapter` when you get response

```
mAdapter = new AccountPickerAdapter(getActivity(),getChildFragmentManager(), userWalletList);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(AccountPickerDialog.this)
```

Comment: this `getItemByPos` is not accessible from the AccountPickerDialog class

Comment: nvm, i hadn't called this earlier `private AccountPickerAdapter mAdapter;`

Comment: really? getItemByPos can not call? see the updated answer you have to init mAdapter

Comment: This works I'm able to get the selected recycler item, however I still cant update the linear layout, I have edited my answer to make it clearer

Comment: updated, check it again, haha please specify question clearly in the future.

Comment: i have a question, what if I need to update the linear layout of another different view, I can't use the same `public void onItemClick(int position, View v) {` as it would provide null pointers in the other layout class  for the new view